# Laravel Page Not Found after Copy Existing Directory to New

Tags: php, laravel, apache

On my old directory, my web page runs normally. then I copied old directory to new directory (100% same).

on the new directory, I request URL `http://localhost/public/api/v1/greeting-chat` then come to this error:

> **The requested URL /public/api/v1/greeting-chat was not found on this server.**

I have restarted apache, I have run `php artisan route:list` -  the route is in there

any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: Try following commands to clear thing and check again
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan optimize

Comment: Thanks @SagarSainkar i ll try

Comment: When you copied the folders the `.htaccess` file may not have been brought across (often a problem on macOS). Check that it exists in your new folder.

Comment: Shouldn't your URL suppose to be `localhost:8000/api/v1/greeting-chat` where `8000` is the port number?

Comment: @SaiyanPrince not, its typo. The complete url, is exist on my vps with custom domain. Running using apache